# Heroku Timeouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I updated my ruby => bundler => rails => heroku toolbelt => heroku gem

Since then I am facing issues connecting to heroku

### Any one getting these?

Here is the heroku version

```
✗ heroku version
heroku-toolbelt/3.41.5 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
heroku-cli/4.23.0-32ec41f (amd64-darwin) go1.5.1
=== Installed Plugins
heroku-accounts
heroku-apps@0.2.1
heroku-fork@3.1.4
heroku-git@2.4.1
heroku-local@4.0.2
heroku-pg-transfer
heroku-run@2.5.3
heroku-status@1.2.1

updating Heroku CLI...done. Updated to 3.42.2
```

Here are the errors

```
heroku run rails console
Running `rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.2950
 !
 !    Timeout awaiting dyno, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#timeout-awaiting-process
```

---

```
telnet rendezvous.heroku.com 5000
Trying 50.19.103.36...
telnet: connect to address 50.19.103.36: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

---

**Update**

I thought this was fixed after a heroku outage, but this still happens intermittently for me.

Comment: Have you ensured the port isn't blocked as explained in the help doc? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#timeout-awaiting-process

Comment: I am working from a personal Mac. I really doubt if calling Comcast (Internet provider) would help in this case. Also given it all stopped working after upgrading its prob related to that.